# Building a survey from questions stored in mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm new to the MEAN stack and am building a web survey on the standard Express framework (i.e. from express generator--I used ejs). I have the front end, and the mongoose models written, but am a little stumped as to how to connect the two.

Essentially, I want to use Angular to insert questions stored in a mongodb into a form and then record submission.

Right now I'm working with a test case to sort out what works, so I can generalize it.

model: test.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, default: 'test'}
});

mongoose.model('test', TestSchema);
```

route: test.js

```
var test = require('../models/test');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/tests').get(function(req, res) {
  Test.find(function(err, tests) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }

    res.json(tests);
  });
});

router.route('/tests').post(function(req, res) {
  var test = new Test(req.body);

  test.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }

    res.send({ message: 'Test Added' });
  });
});
```

I know I need to link the route into my app.js file with a line a long the lines of:

```
var tests = require('./routes/tests');
```

But I'm unclear as to how to work it into an angular controller. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your front end code, add a service that listens to the /tests endpoint. If you are using $resource, it would only be a few lines of code:

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('Tests', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('tests/:testId', 
    { 
        testId: '@_id'
    }, 
    {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}
]);
```

Then in your controller, inject this service. Make restful calls using the service.
Here is a sample code to create a new test object, assuming that you have a create for this controller from where you enter the name in a textbox and hit a button that is bound on click to the create function:

```
angular.module('mymodule').controller('TestsController', ['$scope',  'Tests',
function($scope, Tests) {

    $scope.create = function() {
        var test = new Tests ({
            name: this.name 
        });

        checkbox.$save(function(response) {             
            //redirect somewhere or show success message
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: though I do seem to keep getting a 'service not defined error': https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=

Comment: Does the file in which you created the service get loaded to the front end. Have you included it in on the html page that loads from the server?

Comment: Yes, if I comment out the service and the new controller and add a basic controller (i.e. something that just prints out hello world) everything works fine.

Comment: So the controller loads. But can you confirm that the file the service is in loads as well. You can verify that by seeing the list of source files in chrome dev tools. Just to be sure, you can also put all the service code in the same file in the controller (just for debugging purposes) and see what happens. Other thing to look for, is the module name defined at the beginning of the service definition, the same as the one defined for the controller?